# How can I code command line interface?

Tags: c, user-interface, command-line, posix

I'm a GUI developer. I have used many of GUI frameworks including WindowsForms, Flash, HTML, AppKit, UIKit. I can say I know how to code GUI.

Suddenly I got an interest about command-line-interface. Like VI or Emacs. Because I started programming with GUI, I don't have any experience or knowledge about CLI. Of course, I used VI, and unix shells, however I don't know how to implement them. And I want to know it.

For GUIs, most basic construct for all graphical stuff is lowest-level drawing method. For software implementations, it's CPU based drawing method. For hardware accelerated implementations, it's OpenGL based method. All GUI stuffs are built on top of them. What can I expect for CLI? How can I draw text on console and blink the caret?

I just need first step. Like a function name or library name. For example, something like `setPixel()` function. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.
I prefer General Unix system. Primarily POSIX. And currently I'm using Mac OS X. Of course language is C.

Comment: At the end of the day it "just" comes down to sending and receiving terminal escape sequences such as [VT-100 escape codes](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php). However, this is painful to do by hand and there are so very many [slightly] different terminals/terminal capabilities! Libraries highly recommended :)

Comment: I won't change the question for you because you are >4800 rep, but you should add the [Posix] and [C] tags

Comment: @pst OK. If they're not compatible a lot, I won't go there. Maybe.

Comment: Just so that you know (and it wasn't in your question) Windows doesn't natively supports ANSI escape codes in console.

Comment: @Eonil Let's just put it this way ... UNIX systems a [termcap database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) for dealing with it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to dive head-on, learn ncurses and type away. This is THE way to write console gfx apps.

If you want to learn the basics, [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). This is the mechanics of how ncurses interfaces with the terminal doing its magics. It's quite manageable by itself and an interesting subject to learn - you just print out an escape sequence and the cursor moves to specific point on screen or whatever you print out is printed in inverse video and so on. And from there, it's crude semigraphics using upper half of 256 ASCII codes and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Look into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readline because it gives you things like command line history, tab completion etc...

Also ncurse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses for console based dialog screens.

Comment: Thanks you for answering. It looks slightly more higher level than I expected, anyway I'll take a look. :)

Answer (score 2):

In which language are you experimenting ? For which os ? ncurses, as already stated, is a good lib for unix like systems, but if you're under ms windows, I guess things will get a little bit different.

Another thing to keep in mind is that depending on your OS, you may have to learn & understand termcap entries or inherited DOS legacy.

For *nix you have to check some graph library if you want to experiment with pixels and alikes. If it's just normal terminal interface you need, ncurses IS the starting point (until you want to do it all by hands with termcap and escapes).

There're plenty of frameworks for developing text/terminal based UI, more or less they give everything you need. But if you want to trace a line from pixel (1,1) to pixel (10, 24), I think you should focus on graphics libs. (OpenGL in *nix env is easily obtained via MESA library).

On win32, well, DirectX, but they're a reall hassle.

Comment: Oh thank you for care. I missed that. I updated my question to present my target platform.

Comment: well if it comes down to graphics things will get screwed a bit. For example in good old MS-DOS days (or HP-UX days as well), you had to rely on a graphic subsystem (setting graph mode on DOS, relying on X on *nix). If I recall well, the simplest graphic toolkit was "The Turtle" - yeah good old Pascal :) Edited with more insights on graphics.

Answer (score 1):

C has a library for better manipulation of the terminal: `ncurses`